# How was the concept of tree (abstract data type) first proposed?

Tags: data-structures, tree, abstract-data-type

I'm learning the tree (abstract data type), and I don't just want to know about the definition and operations, which can be found without any difficulty.

I want more, especially who propose  the tree, and in what situation did he work out the tree structure.  Because besides using the tree, I'm interested in why some people can design such a usefull data structure.

By the way, when I learn Stack(another data structure), I find a short [history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)#History) that tell me how the stack were proposed in Wikipedia.  But when it comes to [Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)), there is no such a history.

So, could anybody tell me something about the history of Tree?  Thanks!

Comment: The tree as a hierarchical structure has been around since at least the third century CE. See [Porphyrian tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porphyrian_tree). You might also be interested in the answers to this question: http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2200/what-is-the-first-historical-reference-to-the-binary-search-algorithm

Comment: And, finally, there's [Graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory), which was an active area of research long before computers were invented, and which includes the study of tree structures.